# Removing Duplicated Lines From a Large File

Tags: php

I want to remove duplicated line from a `txt file` and keep only unique lines but the file is too big up to 700mb, I have searched throughout StackOverflow, but the solutions will use much memory, I finally saw a much simpler way that uses less memory after much research, but it only remove duplicated, I want it to keep only one of the line instead of deleting the duplicated line entirely.
BELOW IS THE CODE

```
$lines = array();
$fd = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
while ($line = fgets($fd)) {
    $line = rtrim($line, "\r\n"); // ignore the newline
    if (array_key_exists($line, $lines)) {
        $lines[$line]++;
    } else {
        $lines[$line] = 1;
    }
}
fclose($fd);
$fd = fopen("outputfile.txt", "w");
foreach ($lines as $line => $count) {
    if ($count == 1) {
        fputs($fd, "$line" . PHP_EOL); // add the newlines back
    }
}
```

with the above code if I have

```
happy
smile
stack
happy
smile
flow
```

it will remove `happy` and `smile` entire. but I want to keep only one happy and one smile instead of deleting them entire

I don't know much on PHP please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want and will be slightly more efficient.

```
$lines = array();
$fd = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
while ($line = fgets($fd)) {
    $line = rtrim($line, "\r\n"); // ignore the newline
    $lines[$line] = 1;
}
fclose($fd);
$fd = fopen("outputfile.txt", "w");
foreach ($lines as $line => $count) {
    fputs($fd, "$line" . PHP_EOL); // add the newlines back
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this was exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_unique function if you are using php

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Linux system, you can use the backtick **`** operator to execute shell commands.

```
<?php

$inputfile = escapeshellarg('test.txt');
$outputfile = escapeshellarg('unique.txt');
`sort $inputfile | uniq > $outputfile`;
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way is to not bother counting lines, but storing the lines in the array.  If the new line does not exist in the array then write it to the output and add it in.  This also does it in one pass rather than two loops.

```
$lines = array();
$input = fopen("a.txt", "r");
$output = fopen("outputfile.txt", "w");
while ($line = fgets($input)) {
    if (!in_array($line, $lines)) {
        fputs($output, $line);
        $lines[] = $line;
    }
}
fclose($input);
fclose($output);
```

You may still have memory problems as you are storing each unique line in memory, you may have to try it and see how well it performs.

It may be quicker to use keys for the lines as this stops having to scan the array, but again something you will have to try...

```
while ($line = fgets($input)) {
    if (!array_key_exists($line, $lines)) {
        fputs($output, $line);
        $lines[$line] = '';
    }
}
```